# jQuery: .nextUntil() of a class

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

How can I find all elements of a class after a specified element, and before a specified element.

jQuery `.nextUntil()` returns ***all*** elements after a selector, up until the specified selector, but I need to find all elements after an element and before an element, that are of a certain class.

I need to do this without any parent selectors.

So in this snippet, I would want all of the elements of the class `yes` to be highlighted yellow.

```js
var el = $('.start').nextUntil('.stop');
el.css('background', 'yellow');
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="start">start</div>
<div class="yes">yes</div>
<div class="no">no</div>
<div class="yes">yes</div>
<div class="no">no</div>
<div class="yes">yes</div>
<div class="no">no</div>
<div class="stop">stop</div>
```

I wish I could do something like `$('.start').nextAll('.yes').until('.stop');` why is that not a thing?

Comment: Given the example, are you sure you're not overcomplicating this? Why not just `$('.yes').css('background', 'yellow')`?

Comment: `$('.start').nextUntil('.stop').filter('.yes').css('backgroundColor', 'yellow')`

Comment: yes because I am inserting elements between two elements, and I need to find that specific element, as there could be multiple `start, yes, stop` on a page, that's just the simplest example I could come up with. Idk how to correctly explain it .-.

Comment: @Taplar Awesome, I didn't know about `.filter()`. Can you put this in an answer please?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$('.start').nextUntil('.stop').filter('.yes').css('backgroundColor', 'yellow')
```

`nextUntil` can be used to get a subset of elements.  If you want to further reduce that subset, you can use `filter` to get a more granular set to manipulate.

Answer (score 0):

You can apply the modification only to the `yes` class circoscripted inside a `start` class:

```js
$('.start-wrapper .yes').css('background', 'yellow');
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="start-wrapper">
  <div class="start">start</div>
  <div class="yes">yes</div>
  <div class="no">no</div>
  <div class="yes">yes</div>
  <div class="no">no</div>
  <div class="yes">yes</div>
  <div class="no">no</div>
  <div class="stop">stop</div>
</div>
```

Comment: I stated in my question that I need to find `yes` without the use of parent selectors.